# Adsense: How to show more than 3 google ads?

Tags: wordpress, mobile, adsense

I created a mobile version for my website. For some reason, I can see just 3 Adsense ads on the homepage. I read  that there is a limit of 3 ads per page. How can I make the site show more than 3 ads like the mobile version of mashable.com?

my site: nocamels.com

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [policy](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en-GB) states, you cannot:

> Currently, AdSense publishers may place up to three AdSense for content units on one web page.

However, if you become a premium publisher (probably having a website with a very high visitors count, but there are no officially published terms about that) as I assume Mashable is, then you can negotiate this limit.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know where can I apply to be a premium publisher?

Comment: @YuvalH Sorry, no idea; you'll probably have to contact Google directly about that, but I assume if you reach the numbers they are asking they'll probably contact you themselves. :)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try doing that.

Comment: @YuvalH By the way, since you accepted this answer, you might also want to upvote it as well.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't allow me... It says that I need 15 rep points :(

Comment: I just want to mention that a site with that little views obviously gets not accepted. The site is just nothing worth compared to other sites (I have a website too which is even less popular than yours, I just wanted to say that it's not enough)